# Shiny: select variables to table

Tags: r, shiny

I have one question to open the topic already. Well, I'm trying to do a similar app to this one Shiny: dynamic dataframe construction; renderUI, observe, reactiveValues. And I would like to add a new category at the beginning which will select the variables from the table. I can not combine variables with other elements in an application. Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
As you can see on the graphics program does not work well. [image]
Below is a script

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(Category1 = rep(letters[1:3],each=15),
                   Info = paste("Text info",1:45),
                   Category2 = sample(letters[15:20],45,replace=T),
                   Size = sample(1:100, 45),
                   MoreStuff = paste("More Stuff",1:45))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("show_vars", "Columns to show:",
                     choices = colnames(data), multiple = TRUE,
                     selected = c("Category1","Info","Category2")),
      uiOutput("category1"),
      uiOutput("category2"),
      uiOutput("sizeslider")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {


  data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$table)
    if(input$table == "All"){
      return(data)
    } 
    data[,names(data) %in% input$show_vars]
  })


  output$category1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat1', 'Choose Cat 1', choices = c("All",sort(as.character(unique(data$Category1)))),selected = "All")
  })

  df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1,{
    if(input$cat1=="All") {df_subset <- data}
    else{df_subset <- data[data$Category1 == input$cat1,]}
  })

  df_subset1 <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$cat2)){df_subset()} else {df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2,]}
  })

  output$category2 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat2', 'Choose Cat 2 (optional):', choices = sort(as.character(unique(df_subset()$Category2))), multiple = TRUE,options=NULL)
  })

  output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("size", label = "Size Range", min=min(df_subset1()$Size), max=max(df_subset1()$Size), value = c(min(df_subset1()$Size),max(df_subset1()$Size)))
  })

  df_subset2 <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$size)){df_subset1()} else {df_subset1()[df_subset1()$Size >= input$size[1] & df_subset1()$Size <= input$size[2],]}
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    df_subset2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The issue is irrespective of what you select all the columns are displayed?

Comment: I want to be able to select which columns are shown. So it is in the example, but as you can see still showing up all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `data2` since you are not using it and instead you can just use the same condition to filter columns with %in% everywhere you are displaying the dataframe.

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(Category1 = rep(letters[1:3],each=15),
                   Info = paste("Text info",1:45),
                   Category2 = sample(letters[15:20],45,replace=T),
                   Size = sample(1:100, 45),
                   MoreStuff = paste("More Stuff",1:45))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("show_vars", "Columns to show:",
                     choices = colnames(data), multiple = TRUE,
                     selected = c("Category1","Info","Category2")),
      uiOutput("category1"),
      uiOutput("category2"),
      uiOutput("sizeslider")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {





  output$category1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat1', 'Choose Cat 1', choices = c("All",sort(as.character(unique(data$Category1)))),selected = "All")
  })

  df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1,{
    if(input$cat1=="All") {df_subset <- data}
    else{df_subset <- data[data$Category1 == input$cat1,names(data) %in% input$show_vars]}
  })

  df_subset1 <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$cat2)){df_subset()} else {df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2,names(data) %in% input$show_vars]}
  })

  output$category2 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat2', 'Choose Cat 2 (optional):', choices = sort(as.character(unique(df_subset()$Category2))), multiple = TRUE,options=NULL)
  })

  output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("size", label = "Size Range", min=min(df_subset1()$Size), max=max(df_subset1()$Size), value = c(min(df_subset1()$Size),max(df_subset1()$Size)))
  })

  df_subset2 <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$size)){df_subset1()} else {df_subset1()[df_subset1()$Size >= input$size[1] & df_subset1()$Size <= input$size[2],names(data) %in% input$show_vars]}
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    df_subset2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Because changing the other variables (category, sizeslider) displays a lot of warnings and errors.

Comment: @Kim It is showing warning when you don't have numeric column and yet you have numeric slider. But isn't that what you wanted by allowing someone to select the column?

Comment: There have been no warnings or errors before, most often the message is: undefined columns selected.

Comment: What's the purpose of having numeric field when that column is not going to be selected and what will it help?

Comment: Is it possible to hide the numeric field when this column is not selected and vice versa?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159692/discussion-between-kim-and-amrrs).